# C# Async - How many objects are created here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to understand the code I wrote,

```
for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    ExecuteCMD("/c robocopy C:\\Source D:\\Source /MIR", true);
}

public async void ExecuteCMD(string cmdLine, bool waitForExit)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        ExecuteProcess proc = new ExecuteProcess(cmdLine, waitForExit);
        proc.Execute();
    } );
}
```

The async method ExecuteCMD will run in a loop for 5 times. I know async doesn't create new threads. So, are there 5 objects created with the same name ('proc') in the same thread? Please explain

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: they are seperate  5 threads

Comment: `async void` is a typical mistake. Meanwhile, "async/await doesn't create new threads" only if you use it correctly.

Comment: @LexLi Is it a mistake? The method is not being awaited and we do not know of any requirement to await it. What are the consequences? Well done for pointing out a _'problem'_ in amateur code. Have a gold star.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx You hit the first two guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, so you will *most likely* (see Stephen Cleary's comment) end up on the default `TaskScheduler`, which happens to execute work on thread pool threads. Your `ExecuteProcess` allocation and `Execute` call will therefore occur 5 times, as expected, on thread pool threads (see above point re default scheduler) - and most likely in parallel to each other, *and* in parallel to your `for` loop (this last part might be difficult to wrap your head around, but that's the whole problem with `async void` - the execution order is non-deterministic; more on that later).

You are *sort of* right in that `async/await` does not necessarily create new threads. `async/await` is all about chaining tasks and their continuations so that they execute in correct order with respect to each other. Where the actual `Task` runs is determined by how that `Task` is created. Here you are *explicitly* requesting your work to be pushed out to the thread pool, because that is where `Task`s created by `Task.Factory.StartNew` execute.

Others have pointed out that you might be using `async void` erroneously - possibly due to lack of understanding. `async void` is only good for scheduling work in a fire-and-forget manner, and this work needs to be self-contained, complete with its own exception handling and concurrency controls. Because your `async void` will run unobserved, *in parallel* to the rest of your code. It's like saying: "I want this piece of code to run at some point in the future. I don't need to know when it completes or whether it raised any exceptions - I'll just wait until it hits the first `await`, and then carry on executing my own work - and the rest of the `async void` will proceed on its own, in parallel, without supervision". Because of this, if you put some code *after* your `for` loop, it will most likely execute *before* your `ExecuteProcess` work, which may or may not be what you want.

Here's a step-by-step view of what actually happens in your application.

You hit the first iteration of the `for` loop on the main thread. The runtime calls `ExecuteCMD`, as if it were any other, synchronous method call. It enters the method and executes the code *preceding* the `await`, still as part of the first `for` loop iteration, on the main thread. Then it *schedules* some work on the thread pool via `Task.Factory.StartNew`. This work will execute at some point in the future on, let's say, thread pool thread #1. The `Task` returned by `Task.Factory.StartNew` is then awaited. This task cannot possibly complete synchronously, so the `await` *schedules* the rest of your `async void` to run in the future (on the main thread, after the task created by `Task.Factory.StartNew` has completed) and yields. At this point your `ExecuteProcess` work probably hasn't even started yet, but the main thread is already free to jump to the second iteration of the `for` loop. It does exactly that, which results in another task being scheduled to run on, say, thread pool thread #2, at some point in the future - followed by yet another continuation scheduled to run on the main thread. The `for` loop then jumps to the next item.

By the time your `for` loop ends, you will most likely have 5 `Task`s waiting to execute on thread pool threads, followed by 5 continuation `Task`s waiting to execute on the main thread. They will all complete at some point in the future. Your code won't know when because you told it that you don't care (by using `async void`).

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` is notorious in its scheduler choosing behavior. In particular, it uses the *current* scheduler, *not* the default scheduler. This is one reason that `Task.Run` is superior.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean your `ExecuteProcess proc` Object? This is a local variable of your lambda function. So there is no conflict in your code.

The Lambda

```
() => 
{
    ExecuteProcess proc = new ExecuteProcess(cmdLine, waitForExit);
    proc.Execute();
}
```

is called 5 Times but every call creates only one instance of `ExecuteProcess` for the variable `proc`.